# Get the row and column number from within a cell in Excel using only formulas without macros

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there a way to get the row and column of any given cell by inserting a formula into that cell?

So cell A1 would say (1,1), C2 would read (3, 2), etc. This would be kind of a self reference in a way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
=CONCATENATE("(",COLUMN(A1), ", ",ROW(A1),")")
```

Edit: Removed unnecessary function call.

Comment: Thanks. How does your answer differ from chris neilsen's where he uses COLUMN() without passing an argument?

Comment: His returns the address of the containing cell while mine returns the address of a specified cell (which can be the containing cell).

Comment: Thanks it helps .

Answer (score 16):

To self reference a cell, use

```
=CONCATENATE("(",COLUMN(), ", ",ROW(),")")
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, your answer helped.

Answer (score 1):

```
=CONCATENATE("(";COLUMN(A1);",";ROW(A1);")")
```

=>(1,1)

Comment: =CONCATENATE("(";COLUMN(C2);",";ROW(C2);")") =>(3,2)